# Non-standard UUID generation (such as using counters)

Tags: uuid, rfc

I find myself often in a situation where I want to generate a very large number of UUIDs rapidly.  It would be desirable to generate one UUID "properly," then manipulate it to generate the rest.  For example, I might just "add one" to the lowest bits of the UUID.

For most of my applications, I control the consumers of the UUIDs sufficiently that I can guarantee that they accept these UUIDs without complication.  I'm curious whether I could say the same if I did not control the consumers.

In particular, I'm interested in the following three algorithms:

- Generate a UUID v5 with some unique string.  For subsequent UUIDs, add 1 to the "node" section (last bytes)
- Generate a UUID v4 from a pseudorandom source.  Again, add 1 to the "node" section for subsequent UUIDs (in effect, using a tainted random number source with a strong correlation to the first number)
- Generate a UUIDv5 with some unique string.  Manually change the version number to v4, and begin adding 1 for subsequent UUIDs.

All of these are clearly not standard by the intent of the standard.  However, are there any issues which would cause this to run afowl of the letter of the [law](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), just just the spirit?